# Errors while trying to upgrade MySQL server from 5.7 to 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0, mysql-error-2002, mysql-error-2003

I don't know if I am not doing something correctly or if some flaw is occurring that I can't see. Below are the steps I am taking to try to set up the server but I must be missing something.

1)Add APT repository:

$ wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb

2)Configuring mysql-apt-config screen

Select MySQL server & cluster (Currently selected: mysql 8.0)

Select mysql-8.0 as the server version to be received

Finally, select ok

3)Updating and installing MySQL server

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server

When I do this the following shows:

[The errors I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJlXq.jpg)

I enter the command "mysql -u root -p" and enter my password. The terminal displays the error 2002 (HY000): can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2). I search for the sock using the command "sudo find / -type s" and the socket doesn't show up in the list. Through files and terminal, I navigate to the directory '/var/run/mysqld' and would expect to find some files, but nothing shows up there. So far I have tried to completely uninstall mysql from my machine and reinstall but get the same result. Otherwise, Ubuntu has been upgraded and updated and I have MySQL Workbench 8.0.20.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get everything working correctly. I was able to make the installation but ended up possibly losing my database so I will have to just recreate it.

This source was very helpful:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389747/error-processing-package-mysql-community-server-during-apt-get-upgrade